# Running CMD command on windows service

Tags: vb.net, process, windows-services, cmd

I have created a windows service that requires executing an EXE file with the CMD process. I have used the following code:

```
  Str = "C:\PCounter\Staff\account.exe CHARGE " & Name & " " & Amount & " TO" & Id
  Dim procStartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Str)
  procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
  procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
  procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
  Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
  proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo
  proc.Start()
  proc.Dispose()
```

However the above code will return

> system cannot find the file specified

I have tried same code on the Windows form, and its works fine. To make sure the path is correct I have added a text file in the same location as EXE file, and load the content of the text file in the service. It works fine.

I can't think of anything else; I really would appreciate it if you can help me on this.

Comment: Whats throwing the error, `proc.Start()`, or is that an error message from the account.exe, indicating that it cannot find a file? Does account.exe need any dlls? My only thought is that perhaps the process is started with the wrong working folder. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx

Comment: I'll point out that you are not invoking CMD.EXE anywhere in that code.  CMD is the command interpretter application.  Perhaps you meant `console` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProcessStartInfo has two properties.  One for the executable to run, and the other for the arguments to pass to the executable.  The symantics for the Arguments property are the exact same as the command line.

You can not include the arguments in the same property as the executable.  They must be separated.

Answer (score 0):

**Create service:**

```
sc create Vm-Symantec04 binPath= "\"C:\App32\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe\" -T ws start \"D:\VM\Sym04\Sym04.vmx\" nogui" depend= "VMAuthdService/VMnetDHCP/VMUSBArbService/VMware NAT Service"  start= auto
```

**Delete service:**

```
sc delete Vm-Symantec04
```